# AWS S3 Buckets Access Errors & Buckets Showing Old Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have S3 buckets that I have been using for years and today when I logged in through the console to manually upload some files, I have noticed that all of my buckets are showing ERROR under the access tab.

While I can still see the files, I'm unable to upload or modify any files and also all files in my buckets are showing old versions from December even though I have updated some of the text files just this month. Also, all files are missing their meta tags.

I did not manage or change any permissions in my account in years and I'm the only one with access to these files.

Anyone else had this issue? How can I fix this?

It really feels like AWS had some major failure and replaced my current files with some old backup.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like a permission issue. Are you using your root credentials, or an IAM User? Do the credentials have full S3 access? The "Access" column attempts to determine whether objects are publicly accessible, based upon bucket policies and object ACLs.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for the feedback. Yes, I'm using my root credentials. I'm the only user, I have created the buckets and the files and this is the first time I'm having this issue. I have not changed anything in my root/user account. Even if somehow my credentials got deleted etc, why would files be missing or showing last modified in December when I have updated/uploaded several new versions in January and February. Really, it does look like some old backup restore and all the meta-tags and file permissions are gone. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can check **CloudTrail** to see if there were any API calls that could explain the changes. If you upload a file now, does it get correctly reflected in the console? When you last updated/uploaded new versions, how did you copy them to S3?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for the tip about CloudTrail. It is showing only my access and the buckets errors as `Error code: ObjectLockConfigurationNotFoundError` and Event name `REST.GET.OBJECT_LOCK_CONFIGURATION`. Also, I have tried to create a new bucket, but no luck. Uploading does not work either. As per my file updating, usually, if I have an updated  version, I will delete the old version first and upload a new version. Today, I could not even upload a new file. Again, the files are showing as last modified in December while I work on them on weekly basis. Any ideas about the errors?

Comment: I would concentrate on getting normal functionality before diagnosing the past. You should be able to create a bucket and upload to it. What errors are you experiencing when you try that?

Comment: I agree, I have successfully created a new bucket, however, the same Error appears under the Access column and I get an error every time I try to upload a new file. Unfortunately, it only says "error" with no details while the upload did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be worth creating an IAM user with Administrator access, enabling console login, and logging in as that user to re-test this (or use the awscli with downloaded credentials). Sounds suspiciously like it's permissions-related (or a very unusual bug in S3).

Comment: @jarmod I will try that. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @WayBehind Try checking your object ACL's whether you have removed read/write access of root account for your object. Also ensure that you don't have any active bucket/IAM policy which is restricting access to object.

Comment: @shanbhagsv based on JARMOD suggestions, I have created a new IAM account with admin credentials and I'm still getting errors even when I create a brand new bucket and I cant upload any new files even from the new IAM admin account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue (except of the old files part). In my case it was a browser plugin called "Avira Browserschutz", a similar plugin to adblock, which caused it. Other plugins such as uBlock Origin might result in identical behavior.

Test it by disabling said plugins or visit AWS in incognito mode.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It turned out it was the AdGuard Adblocker plugin.